Performance Issues with External API Calls in GCP Cloud Functions 2nd Gen
I'm currently using Google Cloud Platform's 2nd generation Cloud Functions to handle some processing tasks. My function needs to call several external APIs, and I'm noticing significant performance issues with these calls.
Environment:

Platform: GCP Cloud Functions (2nd Gen)
Runtime: Node.js 20
Resource Allocation: Tried increasing memory and CPU, but no improvement
External API Call Duration: Ranges from 100 ms to 3000 ms; occasionally takes 20-30 seconds

Problem:
I expected API calls to be fast and stable given that GCP is a data center, but I'm encountering highly variable response times. Here's a brief overview of the setup:

Network Latency:

Calls to a public API have very inconsistent response times, from milliseconds to several seconds.


Code Structure:

The script itself is straightforward and doesn't involve complex logic or blocking operations that could contribute to the delay.


Resource Management:

I’ve tried increasing memory and CPU allocation, but this didn’t resolve the latency issues.


Observations:

No consistent pattern in the latency spikes; they occur seemingly at random intervals.



Example Code:
Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using to make the API calls:
export const runTest = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.status(200).send({})

  const scheduledTask = req.body as ScheduledTask

  const runner = new ScheduledTaskRunner()
  await runner.run(scheduledTask)

  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    await pingWithAxios()
    await pingWithFetch()
    await pingWithKy()
  }

  console.log('done')
}

export async function pingWithFetch() {
  const start = Date.now()
  await fetch('https://api-prod.reapi.com/ping').then((response) => {
    const end = Date.now()
    console.log('fetch ping response:', response.status, 'time:', end - start, 'ms')
  })
}

export async function pingWithKy() {
  const start = Date.now()
  await ky.get('https://api-prod.reapi.com/ping').then((response) => {
    const end = Date.now()
    console.log('ky ping response:', response.status, 'time:', end - start, 'ms')
  })
}

export async function pingWithAxios() {
  const start = Date.now()
  await axios.get('https://api-prod.reapi.com/ping').then((response) => {
    const end = Date.now()
    console.log('axios ping response:', response.status, 'time:', end - start, 'ms')
  })
}

Screenshot:


Questions:

Network Configuration: Could there be any network configuration settings within GCP that might cause such variability?
Best Practices: Are there any best practices for optimizing external API calls from GCP Cloud Functions?

Any insights or suggestions on how to diagnose and improve the performance of these external API calls would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help!

Put your  res.status(200).send({}) at the end of the function, after the log "done". If it's better, I will explain you why

@guillaumeblaquiere That's it! God thanks. Why is this happening? I did this because my task could take more than one hour to complete so I cannot hold hundreds of http connections. Is there any workaround?

I tried to add as many relevant information as I think useful for you. Don't hesitate to comment to have more detail on some parts.

Serverless environment are great because they are managed by someone else (here Google). However, because it's managed by other, you have to comply with their rules, and do not rely on your assumption. Let me explain.

With Cloud Run, you pay only when a request is being processed, I means between the request reception and the response sending. When a request is processed, you pay for it, and therefore, the CPU is dedicated to your instance(s).
Because you do not pay out of request context, google preempts (throttles) the CPU to share it with other instances that process requests (and therefore pay for them!)

With this context, you can understand that the stuff you do after the response sending is out of request context and the CPU is throttled (in reality only a few % of CPU is still allowed to the instance (less than 5%) to allow the instance to maintain connections, like database connection and others).
Switching the response sending at the end allow the instance to keep 100% of the CPU and to perform with high efficiency your job. It will be also more expensive (because you keep longer the CPU you pay for all the duration you have it).

Now, the max timeout. Indeed, Cloud Run Service has a 1h timeout and you can't extend it.
But, with 1H timeout, you are not performing interactive communication with a user, or a system, your are more in job mode. You run a background process to perform operations.
For that, you can use Cloud Run jobs. Very similar to Cloud Run Service, but you do not invoke it with a HTTP request, but you can run an execution with a HTTP request to the Cloud Run Job API endpoint.
Your container also do not need to expose a webservice. It can perform a simple script and the instance are stopped when your script is stopped.
It's the best service for you, and the timeout can be set to 7 days.

Indeed I shall adopt cloud run jobs! Thanks a lot!

more context - https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation
