Playwright works locally, but fails once deployed on to Google Run
I developed and successfully tested a python script locally that uses Playwright for web scraping.

TLDR: Python script logs into a website, goes to a different page, clicks on a few links and then downloads a CSV
file, which will ultimately be pushed into a Google Big Query Table,
but for the moment, it will simply be returned to the browser for testing
purposes...

I created a dockerfile and pushed the container to the Google Artifact Registry. Finally I deployed the service to Google Run.
here is the main.py
from flask import Flask, request, abort, Response
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright
import asyncio
import pandas as pd
import io

app = Flask(__name__)

# Declare the username and password directly in the code
USERNAME = ""
PASSWORD = ""
DASHBOARD = ""

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Flask is running! Visit /csvdata?url=<your-url> to capture and view the CSV data.'

@app.route('/csvdata')
def capture_and_display_csv():
    # Get the URL from the query string
    url = request.args.get('url')
    
    if not url:
        return abort(400, description="URL parameter is required")
    
    # Run the function to get the CSV data
    csv_data = asyncio.run(get_csv_data(url))
    
    # Convert DataFrame to HTML for display (or just return as plain text)
    csv_html = csv_data.to_html()  # Or use csv_data.to_string() for plain text
    
    return Response(csv_html, mimetype='text/html')

async def get_csv_data(url):
    async with async_playwright() as p:
        browser = await p.chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        page.set_default_timeout(600000)
        
        await page.goto(url, timeout=600000)
        
        # Enter the username and password
        await page.fill('#username', USERNAME)
        await page.fill('#password input', PASSWORD)
        
        # Click the login button
        await page.click('button[type="button"]')        
        await page.wait_for_selector('div.randomDOM"]', timeout=600000)   
        await page.goto(DASHBOARD, timeout=600000)

        await page.click('a.step1')
        await page.click('a.step2')
        await page.click('a.step3')
        await page.click('a.download_link')
        
        # Wait for the download to complete
        download = await page.wait_for_event('download', timeout=600000)
        
        # Save the file content to a variable
        csv_content = await download.path()
        
        # Read the CSV content into a pandas DataFrame
        df = pd.read_csv(csv_content)
        await browser.close()
        return df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

here is the requirements.txt
Flask==2.3.2
playwright==1.39.0
pandas==2.0.3
numpy==1.25.2

As per the question, the problem is that once deployed on Google Run the script times out (in quite a strange fashion, it seems to timeout initially, and then makes a second attempt that also timesout). The logs dont reveal anything that actually fails, in fact as per the below, the logs suggest that the run completed successfully with a 200 document response:

I have cranked up the resources on the Google Run to 8GIG Memory, 8CPUS and 3600 Request Timeout (max), and also as per the code above, explicitly put timeout of page and all wait functions to 10 mins - none of these has yielded a result. Hoping someone knows how to make this work or has any ideas.

Can you avait your get_csv_data function to complete? That's the problem. See explanation in that responses made yesterday on a similar case:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78857914/performance-issues-with-external-api-calls-in-gcp-cloud-functions-2nd-gen/78858398?noredirect=1#comment139034706_78858398

SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function

Of course, I'm totally not a python expert and there is another way to solve it. My point is: do not run background task outside request processing, else your CPU will be throttled (and your instance deleted after 15 minutes). Keep the request response on Cloud Run side up to the processing completion. Again, see my other answer for more details

I converted the script from request to normal procedure, and deployed the container in the Cloud Run Job Service. It has worked, thanks so much.

The solution here is to utilise the Google Cloud Run Job service and redeploy the app as stand alone function and not a Get Request App. This has 2 positive impacts on performance:

No need for flask
Longer and more persistent execution of scripts and hence less timeout issues

